# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.annotation.annotation:1.1.0: Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

i try to add this package `androidx.annotation.annotation:1.1.0` to fix some problem but i get this

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.annotation.annotation:1.1.0:
    Affected Modules: app
this is my build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '26.0-android'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation.annotation:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
}
```

what i can do to fix that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`androidx.annotation.annotation:1.1.0` is not a correct dependancy declaration.

The correct one is

```
androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
```

[Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation#1.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

use this lint options in module build.gradle file

```
lintOptions { 
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' in project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).